# Fixed footer obscure firefox search match

Tags: css, firefox, search, hidden, footer

I have a site with a fixed footer at the bottom of every page. The content area above the footer has a appropriate margin to ensure that content does not hide behind the footer when scrolling down.

However, when a simple text search if performed in the browser (firefox) the search term is usually hidden behind the footer as the page normally (without the footer that is) scrolls to just bring the search term into view.

How can I work around this issue?

I have one idea in mind: Make the content area of a fixed height (browser viewport height - footer height) and give it a scroll instead of the browser. Not the best solution but that is an option. What would be the drawbacks to this option?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this before with one of my own projects but, is this minor inconvenience really important enough for you to alter the layout of your page? I would **not** suggest the fix you are considering simply because it is unnecessarily adding complexity to your code and the user experience will likely suffer (much more so than the problem you're describing).

I would just let it be.

Comment: Personally I think it is a minor inconvenience too. However, a lot of users are asking for some way to mitigate this issue.
And unfortunately, the footer HAS to remain (that is not a negotiable point :( )

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell, your method is really the only way to accomplish what you want. Interior scrollbars are almost always less than ideal, but, if a substantial portion of your audience desires this and you think they will like it, then I guess it is worth it. :-)